# Magento 2 slow - Dom::_getMatchedNode & Dom::_mergeNode taking 15+ seconds

Tags: magento2, slow-response

Magento 2.3.3

New relic is showing that 2 items are causing slow page loads:

```
Magento\Framework\Config\Dom::_getMatchedNode  (8 seconds)
Magento\Framework\Config\Dom::_mergeNode  (6 seconds)
```

I'm trying to debug this but I'm not sure what is causing this.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on or why these methods might be causing issues? (or what these methods are actually doing)

I have disabled ALL 3rd party modules so I only have core Magento modules running. But still the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you disable caches for configuration.
`Magento\Framework\Config\Dom` class responsible for read and merge Magento Configuration in XML format.

You can use `bin/magento cache:status` to verify status of caches and `bin/magento cache:enable` to enable it